# MVC Required field validation is not working if field is inside accordion

Tags: jquery

Required field validation is not working if field is inside accordion.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="BillingDetails" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Billing Details</label>
  <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#regionBillingDetails" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="regionBillingDetails"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color:dodgerblue;margin-top:10px;"></i></span>
  <div class="collapse collapse" id="regionBillingDetails">

    <div id="dvBillCodeEdit">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bill Code:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 pad-l-0">
          <input type="text" name="BillCode" id="drpBillCodeEdit" class="form-control required" placeholder="Bill Code" maxlength="20" value="@Model.BillCode">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: change `class="form-control required"` by `class="form-control" required`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working

Comment: are you using jquery validation?

Comment: yes i have tried function 
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    $("#Form1").validate({
        rules: {
            drpBillCodeEdit: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        ignore: []
    });
});​


but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It will validate correclty,but accordian will be closed and it wont show. try by opening accordian,it will work. you can replace `collapse` by `collapse-open` and try

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#Form1").validate({ 
    rules: 
     { drpBillCodeEdit: { required: true } },
     ignore: [] 
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form name="Form1" id="Form1">


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="BillingDetails" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Billing Details</label>
  <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#regionBillingDetails" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="regionBillingDetails"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="color:dodgerblue;margin-top:10px;"></i></span>
  <div class="collapse-open" id="regionBillingDetails">

    <div id="dvBillCodeEdit">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Bill Code:</label>
          <input type="text" name="BillCode" id="drpBillCodeEdit" class="form-control required" placeholder="Bill Code" maxlength="20" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit">Button</button>
  
  </form>
```

Comment: can anyone suggest me code if we got required field validation error Accordion will automatically expand( field in which error occured)